# preg_replace replace incomplete tags

Tags: regex, preg-replace

i am trying to read a html page using file_get_contents. After I processed the data, there are some incomplete tags for example:

```
</p><p> test test test test</p>
```

In this case there does not have a `<p>` to open `</p>`

or

```
<font color="#333333">abc</font><div><p>go go go go </p>
```

in this case there does not have a `</div>` to close`<div>`

thus I want to use preg_replace to remove all these incomplete tags, in my examples, the extra `</p>` and `<div>` should be removed. How can I do that? these tags can be any valid html5 tags.

Comment: You should use something like PHP Tidy extension for this:  http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should investigate the use of the PHP Tidy extension (http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).  You can use Tidy to clean up malformed HTML based on whatever DOCTYPE you are attempting to validate.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to understand what a "well formed markup document" is in XHTML.
With well formed markup it does not guarantee the tags chosen as a "start end pair(open close)" will be the correct two if their is a spare unpaired tag.

Second, you will need to build a loop to call each tag per iteration from an array repository of the tag types. The tags in the array should be "literals".
Each tag "length" int should be taken and set in the loop before testing for the tag presence.

When the match of the tag pair(open close) is found, preg match puts the section onto an array of copy of matches,position and length, then take the length of the match and its start position from the parts of the preg match return result array(use a debug print-out of the array while developing the script).

Inside each open close pair matched you need to do a sub loop of the same action to check internal tags.

**Synopsis:**
To build such a system as a customised script ranks with an XML well formed document parser and debugger having any valid efficiency.As much it would be a markup debugger for an IDE if it had that as valid efficiency.
Good luck.